# Submit form with two diffrent submit button inside the form by jquery-ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I looked for many answers here but couldn't resolve this. I'm trying to submit form with two different submit button in the form but in the result it is like asking for method and action for the form. Though i have used e.preventDefault()
for preventing default form submission. thanks

Here is my form

```
<form class='detail-button'>
    <input type='hidden' id='sell_id' value='$pro_id' />
    <input type='hidden' id='sell_name' value='$pro_name' />
    <input type='hidden' id='sell_vd' value='$vendor' />
    <input type='submit' id='sell_add' class='btn' value='ADD TO CART'/>
    <input type='submit' id='sell_buy' value='BUY NOW'/>
</form>
```

And here is script used

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sell_add').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var id = $("#sell_id").val();
        var name = $("#sell_name").val();
        var vendor = $("#sell_vd").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "add_to_cart.php",
            data: 'id=' + id + '&name=' + name + '&vendor=' + vendor + '&click=cart',
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#add_status").hide();
            },
            success: function(data) {
                var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                $("#add_status").show();
                $("#add_status").html(result.stat);
                $(".cartqty").html(result.qty);
            }
        });
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sell_buy').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var id = $("#sell_id").val();
        var name = $("#sell_name").val();
        var vendor = $("#sell_vd").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "add_to_cart.php",
            data: 'id=' + id + '&name=' + name + '&vendor=' + vendor + '&click=buy',
            success: function(data) {
                window.location.href = data;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Your submit button type. It will work because you have set event on button click by using its id.

```
<input type='button' id='sell_add' class='btn' value='ADD TO CART'/>
<input type='button' id='sell_buy' value='BUY NOW'/>
```

and submit through JS

```
$(".detail-button").submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

PLease Use :
`detail-button` is Your Form Class

`$('.detail-button').on('submit',function(event){
        // Write Your AJAX Code Here
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script:

```
$('#sell_add, #sell_buy').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $("#sell_id").val();
    var name = $("#sell_name").val();
    var vendor = $("#sell_vd").val();
    var click = this.id == "sell_add" ? "cart" : "buy"; // <---check if clicked button is "sell_add"
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "add_to_cart.php",
        context:this,  // <----------add context to get the clicked button
        data: 'id=' + id + '&name=' + name + '&vendor=' + vendor + '&click='+click ,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("#add_status").hide();
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if(this.id == "sell_id"){ // <--------------execute for sell_add
                var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                $("#add_status").show();
                $("#add_status").html(result.stat);
                $(".cartqty").html(result.qty);
            } else {  // <----------execute for buy.
                window.location.href = data;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

or a better one is to use `data-*` attribute to store specific information:

```
<input type='submit' data-click='cart' id='sell_add' class='btn' value='ADD TO CART'/>
<input type='submit' data-click='buy' id='sell_buy' value='BUY NOW'/>
```

use this script below:

```
$('#sell_add, #sell_buy').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $("#sell_id").val();
    var name = $("#sell_name").val();
    var vendor = $("#sell_vd").val();
    var click = $(this).data('click'); //<------get the data-click here
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "add_to_cart.php",
        data: 'id=' + id + '&name=' + name + '&vendor=' + vendor + '&click='+click,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("#add_status").hide();
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if(click  == "cart"){ // <--------------execute for data-click="cart"
                var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                $("#add_status").show();
                $("#add_status").html(result.stat);
                $(".cartqty").html(result.qty);
            } else {  // <----------execute for data-click="buy".
                window.location.href = data;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i tried this too but here also happening the same. looks like again preventDefault is not working

Comment: Sorry, I had problem of jquery file placement which i had after script and after placing jquery file before script it got resolved btw thanks your code was fine

Comment: @nisha you can accept it as answer if this helped you.

Comment: Sorry i tried to upvote this but stackoverflow has some rule for new users. needed atleast 15 reputation for making upvote public

Answer (score 0):

I propose to use the submit event for submitting the form and a click event for adding to cart. Furthermore change the submit type for "add to cart" to button

Answer (score 0):

See the updated code i have added here.
usually e.preventDefault() work but if u added return false at the end of event then it help much.

see the code snippet might be it will help you

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).on("click","#sell_add",function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $("#sell_id").val();
    var name = $("#sell_name").val();
    var vendor = $("#sell_vd").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "add_to_cart.php",
      data: 'id=' + id + '&name=' + name + '&vendor=' + vendor + '&click=cart',
      beforeSend: function() {
        $("#add_status").hide();
      },
      success: function(data) {
        var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        $("#add_status").show();
        $("#add_status").html(result.stat);
        $(".cartqty").html(result.qty);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });

   $(document).on("click","#sell_buy",function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $("#sell_id").val();
    var name = $("#sell_name").val();
    var vendor = $("#sell_vd").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "add_to_cart.php",
      data: 'id=' + id + '&name=' + name + '&vendor=' + vendor + '&click=buy',
      success: function(data) {
        window.location.href = data;
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class='detail-button'>
  <input type='hidden' id='sell_id' value='$pro_id' />
  <input type='hidden' id='sell_name' value='$pro_name' />
  <input type='hidden' id='sell_vd' value='$vendor' />
  <input type='submit' id='sell_add' class='btn' value='ADD TO CART' />
  <input type='submit' id='sell_buy' value='BUY NOW' />
</form>
```

Comment: `return false` just performs both `e.preventdefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()`, so having both is pointless.